# Django : Register app but has red underline, url does not work

Tags: python, django, eclipse, url

I just created app which name is 'blog' and registered in settings.py in installed app. However unlike other app that I made, this app name shows red underlines and url setting does not work. When I click button it should send me to 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/add' but instead it send me 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/add/' with page not found error.

Here is my settings.py

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
    'blog',
  ]
```

urls.py in project folder

```
from test.test_xml_etree import namespace
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace="blog")),
]
```

This is urls.py in blog app.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from blog import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^delete/$', views.delete, name='delete'),
    url(r'^add/$', views.add, name='add'),

 ]
```

Comment: "this app name shows red underlines" ??? Where ???

Comment: Do you have a __init__.py in the blogs app?

Comment: @kagronick Yes, I have init.py in blogs app.